# Wordpress Javascript Modal Display Doesnt Close

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have a function that opens modal, when I click on a div. It opens ,but when I press X it doesnt close the Modal. Display doesnt change the value to none, but I can change background color and everything else.

UPDATE -> So get the right clasName and correct modal Id, still I can change the whole modals background for etc , but i cant change the display: block value to none, I can change to none thru inspect, but it doesnt work through the selector.

I have it working through my own WordPress loop, where I need to get post ID and Modal Id (), to show the correct content.

FOUND THE PROBLEM.

So when I console log thisBtn Event and click Event I get this in console:
1.pressing click-to-open I get display Block
2. But when I press X (close) I get var model who is NONE, and after that immediately click to open fires and makes it block again. So my mistake is that the X button fires both in the same time, and Im trying to figure it out.
[CONSOLE PICTURE FOR THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEA8g.png)

```
<div id="click-to-open<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" data-modal="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="qodef-event-list-item-holder  <?php  echo get_the_ID(); ?>">

<?php echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/image', 'event-list'); ?>

<div class="qodef-event-list-item-content">
  <div class="qodef-event-list-item-content-holder">
    <div class="qodef-event-list-item-content-inner">
    <?php
    echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/category', 'event-list', '', $params);
    echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/title', 'event-list', '', $params);
    echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/excerpt', 'event-list', '', $params);
    //echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/info', 'event-list', '', $params);
    echo prowess_core_get_shortcode_module_template_part('templates/parts/read-more', 'event-list', '', $params);
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" class="modal" >
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" id="content<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" >
    <span id="close" class="close<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" data-modal="close">&times;</span>
    <p><?php the_content( 'Read more ...' ); ?></p>                                
  </div>
```

**MODAL**

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>");
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    var thisBtn = btn[i];
    thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var modal1 = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
      modal1.style.display = "block";  
    }, false);
}
```

**KRYZIUKAS**

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close<?php echo get_the_ID();?>");
// console.log(span)
  for (var b = 0; b < span.length; b++) {
    var click = span[b];
    click.addEventListener("click", function(){
      var modal = document.getElementById("<?php echo get_the_ID();?>");
      modal.style.display = 'none';
      console.log("modal", modal)
      console.log('modal style--->', modal.style);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: So you are using the result of `get_the_ID()` as a class name in one place, and as an ID in another …? Now that’s confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Photo For Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJHHh.png)

So the problem was the value false in the event listener I needed to change it to true.
Explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp